# Why i have a small accuracy?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a code to train MNIST dataset to work on the street view house number project, but when I run the code I have acc = 0,1

## Import libraries and modules

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.utils import CustomObjectScope
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
```

## 4. Load pre-shuffled MNIST data into train and test sets

```
(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = keras.utils.normalize(X_train,axis=1)
X_test = keras.utils.normalize(X_test, axis=1)
```

## 7. Define model architecture

```
model = Sequential()



model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

## 8. Compile model

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## 9. Fit model on training data

```
model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train), batch_size=32, epochs=3,verbose=1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  And can you clarify your question?  (I assume you mean to ask, "How can I get `acc` better than `0,1`?")

Answer (score 0):

In step 4, are you normalizing the data correctly? If I recall correctly `X_train` has shape `batch, width, height`. I don't really know what you would want to normalize, but `axis=1` doesn't seem it's supposed to be there. I think you should the normalization.

If you still have low accuracy, try training more epochs than 3. 3 epochs are not that many.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why you have an accuracy like that.

1. Your data is not normalized correctly.
2. You are trying to do image recognition with 3 dense layers in 3 epochs, which will not work.
3. There is no optimization in your code.

Look at the https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/ . It is the Keras documentation on working with the MNIST data using neural network.